# How to get JSP Application Context inside a java class

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I'm not very familiar with JSP, so, let's make this question an example:

suppose I have a JSP file (index.jsp) which contain those statement:

```
<% 
MyObject mO = new MyObject();
mO.sayHelloWorld();
%>
```

and in the MyObject.java:

```
public class MyObject(){
    public void sayHelloWorld(){
        //something like getJSPApplicationContext.getOut.println("<p>Hello World</p>");
    }
}
```

is there a simple way to reach this goal (without passing the JSPApplicationContext to my class?)

Maybe I'm doing something really wrong, anyway, thanks for yout help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me use this opportunity to introduce you to the V (View) in [MVC (Model View Controller)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller#Java%3a_Java_Platform.2C_Enterprise_Edition_.28Java_EE.29).

You should generally put data into the view by putting a view bean into the session on your controller. You can think of your class `MyObject` as a view bean as it contains information you want to display in the view. The controller in this case is your servlet (you *do* have a servlet, right?) and would contain the following in its `doGet` or `doPost` method;

```
MyObject myObject = new MyObject("Hello world");
request.setAttribute("myObject", myObject);
```

The next step is to have your JSP display the data from the view bean. You are strongly encouraged to use [JSTL](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/reference/docs/index.html) for this, rather than by putting code snippets in. The JSTL tag `<c:out>` can be used for displaying data in a JSP. Your JSP might contain the following;

```
<p>
<c:out value="${myObject.message}"/>
</p>
```

This will call the `getMessage()` method on the session object 'myObject' and output it on the page.

Just for completeness, your `MyObject` view bean might look like this;

```
public class MyObject
{
  String message;

  public MyObject(String message)
  {
    this.message = message;
  }

  public String getMessage()
  {
    return message;
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, this is not what I need; Sorry for having stolen your time :) I'm quite familiar with MVC, I use Yii framework for production purpose; what I want to do here is to build up a (very small) framawork in Java/Jsp (wich foce MVC architectural pattern :D ) for accademical purpose; Now, I solved that problem but I need some more help. Is there a way from within a java class to display a JSP page (assuming I have reference to the response.out writer) within this class?

Answer (score 2):

This isn't how it is used.

For the purpose you have demonstrated.

You should include a `Servlet` or `jsp` or static `HTML` just to print `Hello World` like

```
<jsp:include page="/staticfile/helloworld.html" />
```

in `helloworld.html`

just

`hello world`

or include servlet

```
<jsp:include page="/helloworldServlet" />
```

and in HelloWorld Servlet `doGet()`

`out.println("hello world");`

**Also See**

- [how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files)
- [about jsp](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsp/info)

Comment: actually, i don't want to create an hello wordwebapp =)
I'm trying to build up a small framework for accademic purpose, and I need some basic information to set up the framework architecture.

Comment: *OK* , I just suggested standard practices :)

Answer (score 0):

Without passing the context to the class method, and without storing it in a ThreadLocal variable (which I think would be a bad idea), I don't see how you could do that.

If your class needs access to the JSP context it probably means that the class should be a JSP fragment or a custom JSP tag (`<custom:sayHello/>`).